# Toggle() Jquery issue

Tags: jquery, togglebutton

I have multiple steps for the user to change his mind from deleting records. In first step, user have two choices 'cancel to exit' to exit the page or proceed with 'delete'. in step 2, When user selects to 'delete' the records; I want to hide the 'cancel to exit' button, just displaying the 'confirm' and 'cancel delete'. How do I hide 'cancel to exit' in step 2?
Here is the example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaur/z32wcrch/11/)

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='button' value='Delete' id='delete' class='button'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='button' value='Cancel to Exit' id='cancel' class='button'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='button' value='Confirm delete' id='deleteconfirm' style='display:none;' class='button confirmationReq'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='button' value='Cancel delete' id='cancel2' style='display:none;' class='button'>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```js
$("input#cancel").click(function () {
    alert("exit");
});
$("input#delete,input#cancel2").click(function () {
    $("input#delete, input#deleteconfirm, input#cancel2").toggle();
});
$("input#deleteconfirm").click(function () {
    alert("Delete");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add something like:

```
$("input#delete").click(function() {
    $("input#cancel").hide();
});
```

Comment: In that case when I click on 'cancel delete' the 'cancel to exit' button does not appear back. I see I can show it with show() but is there any more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an efficient way of toggling the "cancel to exit" button. Just add a `.cancel` or other class to the button that you want to use to toggle the state of the the "cancel to exit" button, then add the following code to your JS:

```
$('.cancel').on('click', function() {
    $('#cancel').toggle();
});
```

Be sure to checkout the demo below.

```js
$("input#cancel").click(function () {
    alert("exit");
});
$("input#delete,input#cancel2").click(function () {
    $("input#delete, input#deleteconfirm, input#cancel2").toggle();
});
$("input#deleteconfirm").click(function () {
    alert("Delete");
});

$('.cancel').on('click', function() {
    $('#cancel').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
    <td>
        <input type='button' value='Delete' id='delete' class='button cancel'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='button' value='Cancel to Exit' id='cancel' class='button'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='button' value='Confirm delete' id='deleteconfirm' style='display:none;' class='button confirmationReq'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='button' value='Cancel delete' id='cancel2' style='display:none;' class='button cancel'>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$("input#delete,input#cancel2").click(function () {
    $("input#delete, input#deleteconfirm, input#cancel2").toggle();
});
```

To this:

```
function toggleStuff1() {
   $("input#deleteconfirm").toggle();
    $("input#cancel2").toggle();

}

function toggleStuff2() {
   $("input#delete").toggle();
    $("input#cancel").toggle();

}

$("input#delete").click(function() {
   toggleStuff1();
   toggleStuff2();
});

$("input#cancel2").click(function() {
    toggleStuff2();
    toggleStuff1();

});
```

You could combine the toggleStuff functions into one, but I generally split these types of functions assuming they may be used independently in other areas of code.